# php error message thru controller, and on php

Tags: php, controller, message

```
if($_POST)
{

    if(array_key_exists("item_id", $_POST))   // asking if the array exists in data.php,
    {


        $item_ids = $_POST["item_id"];       // temp var. to hold the data.php data
        $price=0;
        foreach ($items as $item) 
        {
            foreach($item_ids as $value)
            {
                if($value==$item['id'])      //checking for the ids that were store in array
                 $price+=$item['price'];    // adds price of the ids that are selected
            }

        }
        require_once("view_confirm.php");   //shows the total of price in the view_confirm.php
        die();  


     //if there wasnt any selected boxes its set to true for a statement to be stated on view_items
    }
    $error_no_items_selected =true;
}
```

My function works, I have a problem displaying an error message when the there is no click boxes, I set the value to false above post, `$error_items_selected`, on my `view_items.php` is HTML code, where I also use:

```
<?php if(error_items_selected==true){echo "Click Something";}
```

every time I refresh the page the message already appears,

Comment: `error_items_selected == true` should be `$error_items_selected == true`

Answer (score 1):

In

```
if(error_items_selected==true){echo "Click Something";}
```

`error_items_selected` should have a `$` if it's a variable.

Or `()` if it's a function call.

If you use `error_items_selected` - PHP considers it a constant. And if you don't have such constant, that is obvious, `error_items_selected` is considered a `'error_items_selected'` string which is definitely **true**.

So proper way should be:

```
if ($error_items_selected==true){echo "Click Something";}
```

Also in first code block you use `$error_no_items_selected`. Maybe it's just different variables, but still - check them.